# How to use Auth0 Login with Meteor JS

Tags: meteor, auth0

I have use auth0 with meteor and it works fine in browser but it gives issue with mobile (android and ios).
It give callback url issue.

Comment: Please provide more information, this is currently unanswerable. All answers provided will just be shots in the dark.

Comment: I have used this code and this code runs fine for browsers but it gives callback url issues in mobile platforms  Link: https://github.com/auth0/meteor-accounts-auth0

Answer (score 2):

We have released a new version of our Meteor Package which implements redirect mode and uses the latest version of Lock. You can see the source code and an example here https://github.com/auth0/meteor-auth0 and you can download it from Atmosphere https://atmospherejs.com/auth0/lock

Comment: Question: we don't want to use the lock screen but use our own login form and then call Auth0's  `auth/ro` endpoint to login the user. I can we combine that with the Meteor.account package so that instead of checking the local user it will verify the user registered in Auth0?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using redirect mode on mobile apps per:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/OAuth-for-mobile-Meteor-clients

I've submitted a pull request to update meteor auth0 package in order to work with latest meteor oauth library and support redirect mode.

It was merged but no new release was done. So you could manually add it to your project for now:
https://github.com/auth0/meteor-auth0

Comment: Redirect Mode does not work with auth0. It works fine with google oauth, facebook oauth etc.

Comment: @NavjotAppgyver looks like the new repo owners are clueless and completely blew it away. You can use my mirrors:
https://github.com/mirstan/meteor-auth0
https://github.com/mirstan/meteor-accounts-auth0

and use them as custom packages: 
http://docs.telescopeapp.org/docs/custom-packages

Comment: Thanks @Stan, It looks like you have done great work.

Comment: This is just great , thanks guys for the direction here , also this might be usefull https://github.com/xcv58/meteor-auth0